# C++ drogon HttpController usage

Tags: c++, web

I've began to learning C++ Drogon framework. I read the official and unofficial documents about the Drogon HttpControllers, so i tried to do some simple webserver with 2 endpoint.

Create controller class:

```
--- ApiController.hpp
#pragma once

#include <drogon/HttpController.h>

// internal
#include "forwards.hpp"


class ApiController : public drogon::HttpController<ApiController>
{
  public:
    METHOD_LIST_BEGIN

    METHOD_ADD(ApiController::get, "/get", Get);
    METHOD_ADD(ApiController::post, "/post", Post);

    METHOD_LIST_END
    // your declaration of processing function maybe like this:
    void get(const HttpRequestPtr& req, Callback &&callback);
    void post(const HttpRequestPtr& req, Callback &&callback ) const;
};
```

added controller to cmake and get error when i tried to test "/get". details on screenshoot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkhB2.png)  .
Here is my server config:

```
{
  "listeners": [
    {
      "address": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8080,
      "https": false
    }
  ],
  "app": {
    "server_header_field": ""
  }
}
```

Why drogon don`t use my class when i do  app().run() ? Thanks for you attention, hope that someone can help me with this issue

Comment: What is `app`?  Is it an `ApiController` instance?

Comment: @TimRoberts I that it is entire drogon framework entry point to launch server

Comment: OK, but how does the framework know to instantiate your `ApiController`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Answer to your question will be solution for  my issue

Comment: Now I see.  Those macros create entries in a global table, much like an MFC GUI app.  Because you used `METHOD_ADD`, the URL will actually be `/ApiController/get`.  You might replace METHOD with PATH and see if that works for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah, framework authors write small notice about in documentation. Thank you for you time and desire to help me, i appreciate it. Hope this discussion will save time for another beginners with drogon framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was in URL path that i used to call to my server.

Drogon framework have embedded path mapping, which required from you use "HOST:PORT/namespace/class_name/method" instead of "HOST:PORT/method"

here is some example of valid http-request to my HttpController:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVYhR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community hope now it is more clear